# php table header bold

Tags: php, html

Below is my code which creates a table from a mysql table and sorts them under each department they are in. Now what I have been trying to do is get the department field(header) to be in bold. I have tried

```
<b>
```

but it causes error 500, have also tried

```
<table style='font-weight:bold'>
```

but with no luck. In short terms I would 
like the field Department to be in Bold.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '******';

$database = 'list';
$table = 'users';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<table width='100%' style='font-weight:bold' align='center' border='1'><tr>";

// printing table rows
$temp = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($row['department'] != $temp){
echo "<td colspan=\"4\" align=\"center\">" . $row['department'] . "</td></tr>\n<tr>";
        $temp = $row['department'];
    }
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "</table>"
?>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with php, but html. Tell us what you have tried that lead to a status 500. You just need to either add <strong> around the text or add a class and style it with css.

Comment: do you test any css or html like `<strong> bold text</strong>

Comment: @Connum im still learning php but as i said above i have tried <b> with no luck and <table style='font-weight:bold'>

Comment: Your database query is also prone to SQL injection. Please read up on that matter and on using prepared statements, as otherwise you are opening up huge security holes in your applications.

Comment: @Shayan I have never used <strong> before? where would I put it sir?

Comment: Having an additional html tag result in a server-side error is just not a thing that can happen. ;) you might have made an error while adding the tag. Can you  post the code with your changes that didn't work?

Comment: the <b> tag is deprecated, you should instead use the <strong> tag. Just wrap it around the bold text, as @shayan has shown

Comment: I understand that @Connum but I dont have any text to wrap it under. this is my whole code ( i added the lines i tried to make it work ) I dont know where to put the strong tag to influence the department field ONLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the header into the following:

```
echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n<tr>";
```

1. note that you can echo php variable value inside `"{$variable}"`
2. use style instead.